# Event propagation to siblings (exclude self/transmitter)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I want to send an event to siblings, with exception to the sender of the event. I know that targetScope should contain the sender, but as I'm using $scope.$parent I will not be able to identify where the event was sent from (event.targetScope will be $scope.$parent).

```
$scope.$parent.$broadcast('superevent', data);

$scope.$on('superevent', function(event, data) {
    // I don't want to do anything if it was sent from current $scope

});
```

Currently I have a workaround by including $scope in the event data. Workaround:

```
$scope.$parent.$broadcast('superevent', data, $scope);

$scope.$on('superevent', function(event, data, senderScope) {
    if($scope === senderScope) {
        return; // skip
    }
    // do something with the data
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way to explicitly send an event that excludes the sending scope. I think your workaround (or something equivalent, such as including the scope $id) is the best solution.